# How to deploy a Next.js app on cPanel using manual build

Tags: node.js, next.js, deployment, devops, cpanel

I developed a NextJs App with backend apis in the same project (there's no separate server). I want to deploy my App on Cpanel which is my client's hosting, On searching I found out I need "Setup Node.js App" in Software section, but there isn't one. My client asked hosting provider for this, and he said this :
"node.js is installed at:

[root@server ~]# /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs20/bin/node -v
v20.11.1

its not possible to have it in cPanel in as an app in software section without CloudLinux."

Another solution I got was to make a production build manually and then placing files in the domain directory.

Can someone please help with this part.

I cannot understand the functionality of Cpanel, as it's my first time, so I want an experienced guidance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.